# Duda error Null pointer exception

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception

estoy con bloqueado con un error de un NPE donde no veo donde esta el fallo, por si me pudierais ayudar. El try catch no indica donde esta el error. Es una aplicacion completa que hice hace años, e iba todo perfectamente, y ayer quise ponerme con ella para hacer algun cambio, y mi sorpresa es que me ha dado algun error como este. Esta es la pagina donde se autentica un usuario, lo tipico introduce contraseña y usuario, adjunto el codigo de la servlet, porque el .jsp no seria relevante por lo que creo. Adjunto el codigo, muchas gracias de antemano.

```
import usuarios.Encriptacion;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
/**
 * @author Raul
 */
@WebServlet(name = "login", urlPatterns = {"/login"})
public class login extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //se crea una variable de sesion
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String nombreUsuario = request.getParameter("nombreUsuario");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String permisos = ("administrador");
        //se encripta la contraseña con el metodo de la clase encriptacion y asi compararla con la almacenada
        String encript = Encriptacion.Encriptar(password);
        try {
            ResultSet rs = null;
            //se selecciona la fila que coincida con los datos pasados en la autenticacion
            String consultaSQL = "select NombreUsuario,Password from usuarios2 where NombreUsuario like '" + nombreUsuario + "' and Password like '" + encript + "'and Permisos like '" + permisos + "' ";
            //se llama al la clase JDBC para poder utilizar sus metodos
            JDBC helper = new JDBC();
            /*se llama al metodo de la clase JDBC para hacer una consulta a la base de datos
             pasando como parametro la consulta de SQL*/
             rs = helper.Select(consultaSQL);
            if ((nombreUsuario == null) || (nombreUsuario.equals("")) || (password == null) || (password.equals(""))) {
                String error = "Ha dejado el nombre de usuario y/o la contraseña sin rellenar";
                request.setAttribute("error", error);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } else {
                //si hay una coincidencia en la consulta
                if (rs.next()) {
                    //Se crea la variable de sesion con el nombre del usuario
                    session.setAttribute("nombreUsuario", nombreUsuario);
                    //y se redirige a la pagina de elegir entre las tablas
                    response.sendRedirect("ElegirTabla.jsp");
                    // si los datos no son correcto se declara en la variable el error que luego se mostrara en el .jsp
                } else {
                    String error = "El usuario y/o contraseña son incorrectos";
                    //se prepara para el envio la variable de error
                    request.setAttribute("error", error);
                    //y se envia a la vista para ser mostrada
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
            }
        } //muestra si hay errores
        catch (SQLException sqle) {
            out.println(sqle);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            out.println(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Raúl! Podrás poner el trace de error? Seguro sale la linea que está generando null pointer

Comment: Si esperabas que el algún catch atrape el error, no lo está haciendo. Debugea el código y copia la excepción la pregunta.

Comment: Hola!, ok, ya he entrado al archivo logs del servidor web, y sí ahi me detallaba exactamente donde estaba el error. Muchisimas gracias!